# If electromagnetic waves do not need any medium, then why communication under water is hard or why light does not pass through wall?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

If electromagnetic waves do not need any medium, then why communication under water is hard, or why light does not pass through wall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are particles in water and wall , these particles tend to absorb the incoming electromagnetic radiation / deflect  it hence not needing a medium isn't necessary that the electromagnetic waves pass through it without any intermission right!

Comment: Thanks. It did clear my thought.

Comment: ah no problem :D

Answer (score 5):

"Not needing" a medium is not the same as "not being influenced" by a medium. Just like walking on a sidewalk is easier than wading through the ocean. You don't need the water in order to walk, but the presence of the water influences the amount of effort walking requires.

Comment: +1 Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

You also can walk through vacuum (if you wear the right equipment), but you still can not walk through a wall. it has nothing to do where you can move.